# Docker (in Azure App Service) Running out of space

Tags: docker, azure-web-app-service, jsreport

A docker container running `jsReport` is running out of sapce and the container is failing.

Error in logfile

> 2021-07-13T07: 37: 25.469Z ERROR - Container start failed for xxxx
> with System.AggregateException, One or more errors occurred. (Docker
> API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response= {
> "message": "OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:459: container
> init caused: rootfs_linux.go:59: mounting
> "/var/LWASFiles/Sites/xxxx/appsvctmp" to rootfs at
> "/mnt/data/docker/images/231072.231072/aufs/mnt/7c0065c198b3881806bb293ccee0ceef29b8b619bb47a7512f9b5485557811d5/appsvctmp"
> caused: mkdir
> /mnt/data/docker/images/231072.231072/aufs/mnt/7c0065c198b3881806bb293ccee0ceef29b8b619bb47a7512f9b5485557811d5/appsvctmp:
> no space left on device: unknown" }

Problem started when I was updating to service where each dowload was about 200MB+.
I could probably fix this by removing the service and create a new one OR up the service plan which adds more space.

However I would think there must be a way to use `docker commands` to clean up some of these upgrade files. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: you can use "docker system df" command to see the reclaimable space as shown in below image

https://imgur.com/4Yya2D2 

you can use the docker prune command to remove the unused files and stopped containers. 

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_prune/

Answer (score 1):

- you can use `docker system df` command to see the reclaimable space as shown in below image

[image]

- you can use the docker prune command to remove the unused objects such as images, containers, volumes, and networks
  https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/